# Firestore - Android Java - Transaction

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

I'd like to know how I can stop the transaction operation in Firestore. The function retries many times but I don't need to do this If a condition is satisfied. For example, example provided by online documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

This block will be retried many times if newPopulation > 1000000. What I want to do is:

if newPopulation > 1000000, then leave the transaction operation (don't retry again).

My program allows a customer to make a booking if there are shifts availables. The quantity of slots per shift are 4.

```
                if (shiftQuantity == quantityTotalBookingByShift) {

                    throw new FirebaseFirestoreException(errorMsg1 + shift.toString() + errorMsg2,
                    FirebaseFirestoreException.Code.ABORTED);

                }
```

the code above check if there are 4 slots in the shifts selected by the user, the transaction is aborted. So, this is reason of my question.
my code is below.

```
   public void createBooking(final Booking booking, final Integer quantityTotalBookingByShift, final FirebaseListener listener) {

    final DocumentReference counterDocRef = db.collection(bookingsCollectionPath).document(counterDocument);

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.YYYY");

    final String dateAux = formatter.format(booking.getDate());

    final DocumentReference dateRef = db.collection(bookingByDateCollectionPath).document(dateAux);

    db.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Integer>() {


        @Nullable
        @Override
        public Integer apply(@NonNull Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {

            final String idBookingCounter = "idBooking";
            final String listOfBookings = "ListOfBookings";

            // Read
            DocumentSnapshot counterSnapshot = transaction.get(counterDocRef);

            Integer counter = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(counterSnapshot.getLong(idBookingCounter)));

            counter++;

            booking.setId(counter);

            DocumentSnapshot dateSnapshot = transaction.get(dateRef);

            Integer shiftQuantity;

            for (Shift shift: booking.getShifts()) {

                shiftQuantity = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(dateSnapshot.getLong(shift.getId().toString())));

                if (shiftQuantity == quantityTotalBookingByShift) {

                    throw new FirebaseFirestoreException(errorMsg1 + shift.toString() + errorMsg2,
                    FirebaseFirestoreException.Code.ABORTED);

                }

            }
            // Write counter
            transaction.update(counterDocRef, idBookingCounter, counter);

            //write increment shift booking
            for (Shift shift: booking.getShifts()) {

                shiftQuantity = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(dateSnapshot.getLong(shift.getId().toString()))) + 1;

                transaction.update(dateRef, shift.getId().toString(), shiftQuantity);

            }

            // write bookings
            DocumentReference bookingsDocRef = db.collection(bookingsCollectionPath).document(booking.getId().toString());


            Map<String, Object> bookingToSave = createDataBookingToSave(booking);

            transaction.set(bookingsDocRef, bookingToSave);

            // write booking inside the user subtree
            transaction.set(db.collection(bookingByUserCollectionPath).document(booking.getUser().getId()).collection(listOfBookings).document(booking.getId().toString()), bookingToSave);

            return counter;

        }

        private Map<String, Object> createDataBookingToSave(Booking booking) {


            Map<String, Object> docDataBooking = new HashMap<>();

            docDataBooking.put("id", booking.getId());
            docDataBooking.put("date", new Timestamp(java.sql.Date.valueOf(booking.getDate().toString())));
            docDataBooking.put("createdAt", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
            docDataBooking.put("type", booking.getType());
            docDataBooking.put("comments", booking.getComments());
            docDataBooking.put("vehicle", booking.getVehicle().getNumberPlate());
            docDataBooking.put("status", booking.getStatus());
            docDataBooking.put("shifts", booking.getShifts());
            docDataBooking.put("user", booking.getUser().getId());

            return docDataBooking;

        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Integer aLong) {
                listener.onSuccess(aLong);

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            listener.onFailure(new FirebaseException(e.getMessage()));
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Please share the code you have tried.

Comment: Provide examples, this is very less and raw information.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"